# count the number of nodes after shortest path neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (FooB:Actor { name: 'Foob' }),(AnnaH:Actor { name: 'Anna Hathaway' }), p = shortestPath((Foob)-[act:ACTED_IN*]-(AnnaH))
RETURN p
```

So this returns a graph `p` that is the shortest path from actors Foob to Anna Hathaway. How do I now count all nodes in `p` with a label of "chocolate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
RETURN SIZE([n IN nodes(p) WHERE n:chocolate]) AS count
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [nodes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-nodes) function in conjunction with [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/):

```
MATCH (FooB:Actor { name: 'Foob' }),(AnnaH:Actor { name: 'Anna Hathaway' }), p = shortestPath((Foob)-[act:ACTED_IN*]-(AnnaH))
UNWIND nodes(p) AS n
WITH n AS n
WHERE n.chocolate
RETURN COUNT(*)
```